# Select 2 tables from db and get combined results in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, while-loop

**database table 1 has 3 rows. with ids `id` 1, 2, 3
and database  table 2 has 2 rows, with ids `IDUnique` 4, 5** (table 2 is already generating the `IDUnique` next after last table 1 `id`)

In my html table data, I want to show information combined from those 2 tables, like so:

table:

```
 1. user | name | pass // from table 1

 2. user | name | pass // from table 1

 3. user | name | pass // from table 1

 4. user | name | pass // from table 2

 5. user | name | pass // from table 2
```

What php query should i use to select the 2 tables simoultanesly?

And how it should be the while loop used in html table for that?

Comment: What have you done so far???  Have you tried to Google your problem??  I'm pretty sure there are tons of solution online.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: Not sure what did you mean by **php query**, but you can just use a sql query to get the desired output like answered by @SALEH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `UNION` will suffice

```
SELECT user,name,pass FROM table_1_name
UNION
SELECT user,name,pass FROM table_2_name;
```

For unique dataset irrespective of two tables, use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`